# Tab is removed but its contents are not. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs

I tested this code

https://jsfiddle.net/gerald3ebd/k7abtf35/

and saw that after adding 20 tabs, for example, when deleting a tab, its contents of the deleted tab are not deleted.  I know that in practice it may not be necessary to add as many tabs, but the fact is that it is still a problem.

I tried to remove it by assigning an id like `#detail-n`, but it didn't work. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a very simple mistake. You didn't define the `index` for `v-for`. Here is the working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/tuhin47/Lj5mft67/).